# JavaScript minify in Webpack 5 plugin deprecated

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is there any way to be able to minify in webpack 5? I used this plugin before but it is now obsolete and incompatible with the webpack version, is there an alternative?..
[babel minify deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-minify-webpack-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike earlier Webpack versions, recent versions already include minifiers when in production mode. There is no need to install any additional packages if you're using Webpack 5 and are OK with the defaults: https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#minification

If you want to customize the minification options, you will need to install the TerserWebpackPlugin: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin